# Prove $\underset{x\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{\sin{(1/x})}{1/x}=1$ without L'Hospital's rule.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have the following problem:

> Prove $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin{(1/x})}{1/x}=1$ without L'Hospital's rule.

I tried to use the sandwiches theorem but it didn't work.
My attempt:
  $$-1\leq\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\leq1$$
  $$-x\leq\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}\leq x$$
  $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{-x}=-\infty$$
  $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{x}=\infty$$
  $$-\infty\leq\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}\leq \infty$$
That's where I got stuck.
Thank you very much for your precious time!

Comment: I suppose that the limit is for $x$ and not for $n$. **hint** use $x=\frac 1y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x\not=0$, consider the change of variables $y:=1/x$. If $x\to +\infty$, then $y\to 0^{+}$. So $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}=\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin y}{y}=1.$$
Of course, you can prove the last limit without the L'Hôpital's rule, see [here](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-use-the-squeeze-theorem-to-find-lim-sin-x-x-as-x-approaches-zero).

Comment: The linked text doesn't work btw

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the link.